# How to duplicate database ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, resultset

I would like to duplicate a `ResultSet` that I got from an Oracle database in a JSP page. I thought a simple reassignment would do the trick but it seems to fail. Here is my code:

```
ResultSet rset;
ResultSet new_rset;

rset = alljobsBean.getStatus(conn,1,max ,min );
new_rset = rset;
```

Is this wrong? Or is there a special way of duplicating `ResultSet`s that I dont know?

Comment: (You know that assigning a value to another variable doesn't duplicate it, right?)

Comment: True, bad thinking on my part. But am doing this because I don't want to query the database again for a new Resultset. I just want to take the duplicate RS and modify it differently when displaying it on the JSP page.

Comment: So then just loop it two times on your JSP, displaying it differently each time

Comment: It doesn't work..it always says "Exhausted ResultSet" I think you can only loop through a ResultSet Once. i might be wrong though.

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard way to duplicate a `ResultSet`, short of reading all data and storing it somewhere else. The reason for that is that most `ResultSet` implementations do not store all results in it but simply keep a connection to the database that is used to get the results as needed.

Answer (score 5):

`new_rset = rset;` does not perform any duplication. It simply points `new_rset` to the same object that `rset` is pointing, with both `new_rset` and `rset` being mere references to the same object on the heap.

If you need to duplicate the ResultSet in a JSP, consider using [DTOs](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html) that will contain all the data within the `ResultSet` so that you need not hold a reference to the `ResultSet` in the view. Using a DTO will enable you to close the connection once you have finished reading the `ResultSet`, while you can continue to access the data returned by the SQL query, in a view.

You can also consider using a disconnected [`RowSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) instead of `ResultSet` if you intend to have disconnected access to data, in the similar manner as `ResultSet`, with the added advantage of not having to retain a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you what to get a ResultSet from the database and to show it in a JSP page, you might consider using CachedRowSet. If your goals are more ambitious, you might consider WebRowSet. But for 80% of your needs you would be better of with just loading data from your ResultSet into some DTOs before passing it to JSP.